# Trying to user Powershell to remove bulk computers from AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a simple task I am trying to accomplish. We are decommissioning a lot of old machines, and as part of the process I need to remove the hostnames from AD. I download the list of systems to be decommissioned from our inventory system in CSV files, and my goal is use `Powershell` to import this list, and do a bulk removal.

Problem is, we use `Bitlocker` and as such I cannot use `Remove-ADcomputer` (gives a leaf error). I tried to use the following script using `Remove-ADOjbect`, but no success.

```
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    $Computers = Import-CSV -LiteralPath C:\MIS\scripts\RemoveAD.csv
    foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
    {
    Get-ADComputer -Identity $Computers | Remove-ADobject -Recursive -Confirm:$false
    }
```

I've never done any scripting with Powershell before, just commands to retrieve information. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As for this ... [I've never done any scripting with Powershell befor]... that is all well in good, but that means you need to ramp up before you cause major damage to your host or to your enterprise. See all the ['begining Powershell'] videos on Youtube, or buy and read 'PowerShell in a Month of Lunches'. What did you search for? Meaning your comment on Bitlocker. There are BitLocker cmdlets to deal with this. See the help files and help file examples. You just add the cmdlet in your loop. You can disable BitLocker via GPO as well, and in enterprises, BitLocker is deployed via GPO or MBAM.

Comment: Any script i write won't be immediately deployed, it would be verified by one of our Admins first who is a bit of a Powershell guru but he's out sick atm.  I've done all the Month of Lunches books, Udemy videos, labs, ect. There isn't much more I'm going to get from videos or books.

Comment: ['beginning PowerShell'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27beginning+PowerShell%27)  - ['Manage BitLocker GPO'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27Manage+BitLocker+GPO%27) - ['Manage BitLocker using PowerShell'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27Manage+BitLocker+using+PowerShell%27)

Comment: ['disable bitlocker gpo'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27disable%20bitlocker%20gpo%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27disable%20bitlocker%20gpo%27&sc=5-23&sk=&cvid=77C99EA62CC44716B845DEC21FFA468E) - ['disable bitlocker mbam'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27disable%20bitlocker%20mbam%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27disable%20bitlocker%20mbam%27&sc=2-24&sk=&cvid=E3974E8A4A324D8EAF956F4E6FFA7097)

Comment: Good to hear you did the ramp-up, but you said you've done no scripting. From the basics, there is no difference in using the PowerShell console host and typing interactive commands and writing scripts. The command you type in the console host can be done the same way in a script using the ISE or VSCode. Just type them there, save that, and run the script as you'd need to later. Now for a full-blown PowerShell project, it's a bit different depending on what you need. Meaning calling external exe, forms, .Net stuff et al. Yet, for a simple script, what you have is a fine start. Add BL cmdlets.

Comment: If you are new to scripting I would highly recommend taking a system state backup and duplicate the scenario in an isolated hyper-v environment to do testing. As @postanote has advised you could easily cause major damage (I would like to add not only by using the wrong commands but a typo could result in devastating results and in some cases irreversible.). Testing in an isolated environment will help mitigate this and essentially give you a sandbox not only to test in but also give you a space to further develop your skills.

Answer (score 1):

Quick test on a localhost:

```
$env:COMPUTERNAME | 
 foreach {
 $TargetHost = $PSItem

 Try
 {
    "Processing hostname $PSItem"
    # Check Bitlocker state
    If (Get-BitLockerVolume | Where-Object VolumeStatus -eq 'FullyDecrypted' -ErrorAction Stop)
    {
        # Rest of your code here
        "$TargetHost is not encrypted"

    }
  }
 catch
 {
    # Drive encrypted - Catch errors here
    Write-Warning "$TargetHost is encrypted"
    $PSItem.Exception.Message
 }
}
# Results
<#
Processing hostname localhost
localhost is not encrypted
#>
```

I am not in one of my ADDS labs to try this right now, but something as simple as this, should get you there:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\MIS\scripts\RemoveAD.csv' | 
 foreach {
 $TargetHost = Get-ADComputer -Identity $PSItem

 Try
 {
    "Processing hostname $PSItem"
    # Check Bitlocker state
    If (Get-BitLockerVolume | Where-Object VolumeStatus -eq 'FullyDecrypted' -ErrorAction Stop)
    {
        # Rest of your code here
        Remove-ADobject -Identity $TargetHost -WhatIf
    }
  }
 catch
 {
    # Drive encrypted - Catch errors here
    $PSItem.Exception.Message
    Remove-BitLockerKeyProtector -WhatIf
    Remove-ADobject -Identity $TargetHost -WhatIf
 }
}
```